# Eclipse no muestra colores ni formas. Plugin instalado

Tags: java, eclipse, plugin

No sé si aquí también se puede preguntar sobre eclipse. Si no se puede, disculpen.

Estoy haciendo una actividad en la que tengo que mostrar texto con diferentes colores. Esto lo hago en eclipse, con el plugin ANSI escape in console.

Hace una semana funcionaba perfectamente, este códgio no daba problemas:

```
package tema1_12_EscrituraEnPantalla.colores;
import static tema1_12_EscrituraEnPantalla.colores.Colors.*;

public class ColorsUse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(RED + "Este texto es de color rojo" + RESET);
        System.out.println("Volvemos al color por defecto");
        System.out.println(GREEN + "...y ahora es verde");
        System.out.println(PURPLE_BACKGROUND + "Fondo morado");
        System.out.println(CYAN + WHITE_BACKGROUND + "Fondo blanco con texto celeste");
        System.out.println(CYAN + WHITE_BACKGROUND + BOLD + "Fondo blanco con texto celeste en negrita");
        System.out.println(CYAN + WHITE_BACKGROUND + UNDERLINE + "Fondo blanco con texto celeste subrayado");
        System.out.printf("%s\n",YELLOW + RED_BACKGROUND + (char)9733);//Estrella
        System.out.println(YELLOW + GREEN_BACKGROUND + "Fondo verde con texto amarillo");
        System.out.println(REVERSED + "Fondo amarillo con texto verde usando REVERSED");

    }
}

package tema1_12_EscrituraEnPantalla.colores;

public final class Colors {

    public static final String RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    public static final String BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
    public static final String RED = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
    public static final String YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
    public static final String BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
    public static final String PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
    public static final String CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
    public static final String WHITE = "\u001B[37m";

    public static final String BLACK_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[40m";
    public static final String RED_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[41m";
    public static final String GREEN_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[42m";
    public static final String YELLOW_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[43m";
    public static final String BLUE_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[44m";
    public static final String PURPLE_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[45m";
    public static final String CYAN_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[46m";
    public static final String WHITE_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[47m";

    public static final String BOLD = "\u001B[1m";//Negrita
    public static final String UNDERLINE = "\u001B[4m";//Subrayado
    public static final String REVERSED = "\u001B[7m";//Invierte los colores del texto y del fondo

}
```

Ambos son archivos separados dentro del mismo directorio/paquete.

Como digo, hace una semana funcionaba perfectamente. Mostraba los colores sin problemas, hoy, solo muestra la estrella... ¿Alguien tiene idea de qué pasa?

Comment: Hola! Tu pregunta sí es del tipo de preguntas que es válido hacer por aquí. Bienvenido! Ahora bien, si es [este](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console) plugin, ya hay un par de comentarios diciendo que con la última versión de Eclipse no funciona muy bien. ¿Qué versión de Eclipse y del plugin usas?